# Ассоциативная память

Tags: память

Надо реализовать программу , обеспечивающую выполнение операций поиска и выборки  информации из ассоциативной памяти.
С регистром маски. 
Тип: с полным параллельным доступом.
Способ сравнения: =

Может кто-нибудь объяснить как это делается и что от меня хотят? Может ссылки где почитать. Гугление привело только к аппаратной реализации, а программной нет (

Из методички:
Задание: Написать программу, которая моделирует один вид ассоциативной памяти согласно варианту в виде таблицы данных. Отобразить на экране данные, хранимые в памяти, и содержимое регистров, реализовать операции сравнения согласно варианту над ключевым полем данных.

Comment: Реализацию без поддержки аппаратуры не представляю. Может быть имелась в виду программная модель аппаратуры (simulation) ? А кто именно хочет ?

Comment: да лаба у нас такая. запарили со своей новой программой обучения. я только на втором курсе, а уже блин нейронные сети прошел. дурдом...

Задание: Написать  программу, которая моделирует один вид ассоциативной памяти согласно варианту в виде таблицы данных. Отобразить на экране данные, хранимые в памяти, и содержимое регистров, реализовать операции сравнения согласно варианту над ключевым полем данных.

Comment: Ну да, надо написать программу, симулирующую ассоциативную память.

Comment: > запарили со своей новой программой обучения. я только на втором
> курсе, а уже блин нейронные сети прошел. дурдом...
жаль нельзя поставить вам "-" за этот коммент.
Вы прошли нейронные сети (!) на втором курсе, когда у нас на специальности Программное Обеспечение в не последнем московском вузе в 6м семестре предмет операционные системы 1 семестр! Преподают БЖ на таком уровне, как будто мы в МЧС идем работать, Метрология и стандартизация - как вам название?! И мне например грустно, что нам не рассказывают полезных вещей, а парят только такой вот чушью. Радуйтесь лучше!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Время позднее, поэтому кратко.

Как мне кажется у вас есть массив компараторов. Маска задает активируемые. Внешний цикл программы по тактам работы компаратора. Внутренний по компараторам. В нем для каждого активного моделируете изменение состояния его элементов и выводите это на экран. С точки зрения внешнего процесса компараторы работают параллельно.

Это общая идея. Подробности видимо и составляют суть лабы. Хороший ликбез !

Comment: спасибо. хоть что-то стало проясняться...

Comment: Но может кто подробнее расскажет... 
Вопрос остается открытым...